# Is there a way to set the default contrast settings in Aduience?

Tags: videos, video-player, audience

See below same video comparing image, how to fix Adiuence?

Elementry video player
[image: Elementary Video Player]

VLC video player
[image]

Comment: Can you make it more clear, what are you asking here?

Comment: There seems to be a contrast issue with Audience, take a look at the images, is there a way to set the default contrast settings? Audience is unusable like this

Comment: I don't see any setting of this neigther a gsetting key for Audience... You can post an issue on https://github.com/elementary/videos/issues if you want